# Train on own data set. Mask_RCNN Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling, object-detection, allocation

I'm trying to train my own dataset with Mask_RCNN but i get the following framework errors: [image: Command prompt error]
I have followed the [github tutorial](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) on Mask R-CNN for object detection.

Can i do something to decrease the memory needed to train the data set? Or how can i solve this problem?

Comment: I just solved the same OOM issue, please refer to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52590880/mask-rcnn-resource-exhausted-oom-on-my-own-dataset

Answer (score 0):

Need more information about your pc.I think maybe because the batch size or the image size is too large, it needs more video memory or memory.When I try to train on my own dataset using mask-rcnn-resnet101 in tensorflow-models/object_detection, GTX1080TI 11GB works fine.(batch_size=1,image_size=1000*600).

Comment: Can i change something by dedicating more to my video memory: (https://imgur.com/fx5goGh)

Comment: No,i think you are just use your cpu,tensorflow-gpu need an Nvidia gpu.How much memory do you have?

Comment: My computer stats: Intel Core i7-7700HQ Processor. Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 2 GB. 8 GB DDR4 SDRAM. 256 GB SSD

Comment: Both video ram and ram are too small.Try increasing the size of the page file and just use the tensorflow cpu version.

Comment: It works now, i still get some OOM errors but the trainer start and works.

Comment: Please note that this may crash during training to a certain stage.

Answer (score 0):

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/64145818/11262633, I have described 3 changes you can make to reduce memory utilization in TensorFlow v2.